# Bootstrap - Modify Media Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm using twitter-bootstrap 2.2.8 and rails 4.

Where applicable, I've set up different divs for desktop, tablet and phone using the following classes:

```
.visible-desktop, .visible-tablet, .visible-phone
```

The problem is that, with the way bootstraps media queries work, the iPad(landscape) is using the desktop code not the tablet version which is a major problem.

Is there any way to modify bootstraps media queries so that the tablet max-width is, for example, 1024px instead of the current value (979px)?

Comment: Do you have any scope for upgrading to bootstrap v3? They include classes for that by default in that version.

Comment: No not really, from what I've read there are some significant changes in v3 and we're so far in that going back would mean redoing it all. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind hacking at the Bootstrap CSS you just need to find the Media Queries and change them to whatever width/height you want. You'll find lines like this

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { /*some css*/}
```

Just change these values to whatever you want (the media queries will appear in many different places throughout the css) and that will change the various classes, so in your case there should be something like

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .visible-tablet{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Just change that media query to 1024 and your away. Just be mindful of messing with the media queries too much, as certain classes with widths (such as the various `span*` classes) might start behaving weird once you start messing with the points at which the media queries change.

Comment: Sounds great but where exactly do I find the bootstrap css? The only stylesheet I can see is bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less and the media queries definitely aren't written there!

Comment: Ahh, you're using less. Didn't realise that. I'm afraid I know quite literally nothing about how to use Less and how it works. Maybe someone else who comes across this question can enlighten us. It might also be that you are using Bootstrap from a CDN, in which case you can't modify it. Look in your actual web page at the source and see where bootstrap.css is coming from.

Comment: I'm using twitter-bootstrap-rails so it's a rails gem and so all the styling refers back to that less file. For a first time user, it's kind of a pain to customise.